# Unable to add the dependency of Spring-data into Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-data, spring-boot

I am trying to start from  [Spring boot guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) , and manually include the dependency of Spring-data.

My IDE is eclipse, and I choose to use Gradle to build the project.

Both `build.gradle` and `pom.xml` has been modified, but eclipse still find cannot the libraries of Spring-data (such as `org.springframework.data.*`) during the compile.

Below is my `build.gradle` and `pom.xml`.

Could someone suggest where I go wrong? Thanks!!

**Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'Xiwami'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'Xiwami'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // spring data : mongodb
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb")
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.adarp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Xiwami</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3.2</version> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to manually add the spring data dependencies. Spring Boot provides a starter for that as well. Just add

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```

to `build.gradle`

or

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to `pom.xml` for Spring Data JPA and MongoDB support.

The starter contains all the transitive dependencies you need to work with Spring Data JPA or Mongo.

Check out [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) guide.

As mentioned in the comments, after changing the dependencies don't forget to refresh the project in the IDE

Comment: Thank you very much! After updating the build.gradle, we have to refresh the project by right-clicking the project in the package explore --> choose "Gradle" --> choose "refresh" to clean the project in the eclipse.

Comment: @user3556304  thank you!  Gradle -> refresh is key, not enough to build.